# Disable tightvncserver for a certain user

Tags: permissions, vnc

I don't want user "test" connect to my server with tightvncserver. How I disable this command only for this user, while allowing it for user "myuser"?

What I've done so far:

- I added user "test"

> su
>
> useradd -d /home/test -m test
>
> passwd test

- I added a group "tightvnc" for users allowed to use tightvncserver (only "myuser")

> ```
> addgroup tightvnc
> usermod -a -G tightvnc myuser
> ```

- I changed permission to tightvncserver

> chgrp tightvnc /usr/bin/tightvncserver
>
> chmod o-x /usr/bin/tightvncserver

Now user "test" cannot access tightvncserver ("permission denied"), but neither "myuser" (again "Permission denied") :(

If I do  it reports correctly "myuser tightvnc", while
 gives only "test".

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chgrp myuser /usr/bin/tightvncserver
chmod 744 /usr/bin/tightvncserver
```

That will disable execution for anyone outside of your user group.

From below: try

```
chgrp tightvnc
```

instead? And make sure your user is in the tightvnc group, AND make sure you've logged out and logged back in so your group memberships refresh.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! It works with chmod 754, but I don't want to mix permission of myuser with other users giving them the group "myuser". That's why I created another group "tightvnc"... I can't understand why it doesn't work. Maybe there is something else to do somewhere, but I don't know what :(

Comment: @FIl try `chgrp tightvnc` instead?  And make sure your user is in the `tightvnc` group, AND make sure you've logged out and logged back in so your group memberships refresh.

Comment: "logged out and logged back" <- that's I was missing! Thank you! If you add it as an answer I can accept it. :P